# Swift CKQuery with multiple record types

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckquery

So I'm in good shape on querying specific record types and parsing their data.  What I can't figure out though is how to search across all record types for, as an example, everything that was modified today, regardless of what record type it is.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms that comes to mind is TRUEPREDICATE and metadata. You can read all about them on the apple documentation page. Most of the examples are surprisingly in Objective C, but translating them to swift is easy. The one you need becomes...

In Swift

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
 let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Blah", predicate: predicate)

Which will fetch all records of type Blah, if you want to search multiple databases than you need to do multiple queries, one against each schema I believe.

Comment: Ok, so I would still need to fetch all of the different record types individually then parse them.  There isn't a way to pull all records regardless of `recordType`?

Comment: You already know all the record types, you would have set them up within the iCloudKit dashboard. But yes, I don't think there is a CKQuery that doesn't ask/expect a record type.

Comment: That's really what I was getting at.  Is there a CKQuery that doesn't require a record type.

Comment: No, I don't find any references to building a CKQuery without a record type, its a limitation/feature of cloudkit.